# XSL Template Won't Match

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I have a very simple XSL, and I'm trying to match a servlet element and add a child node. Actually, I need to match a specific servlet, but one thing at a time... No matter what pattern I use, except for *, the template will not match. I've tried it both with and without the namespace. I've also tried absolute and relative paths. Nothing. I'm sure I'm overlooking something wildly obvious here.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
        xmlns:jee="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
        xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee">
        
    <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="ISO-8859-1"/>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="servlet">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
            <init-param>
                <param-name>readonly</param-name>
                <param-value>true</param-value>
            </init-param>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Relevant piece from the XML (the entire document was too big to post). It's just the default web.xml bundled with Tomcat 8, but here it is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<!--
  Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one or more
  contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file distributed with
  this work for additional information regarding copyright ownership.
  The ASF licenses this file to You under the Apache License, Version 2.0
  (the "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance with
  the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at

      http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

  Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
  distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
  WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
  See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
  limitations under the License.
-->
<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee
                      http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
  version="3.1">

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>default</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.apache.catalina.servlets.DefaultServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>debug</param-name>
            <param-value>0</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>listings</param-name>
            <param-value>false</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>jsp</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>fork</param-name>
            <param-value>false</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>xpoweredBy</param-name>
            <param-value>false</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>3</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

<!--
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>ssi</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>
          org.apache.catalina.ssi.SSIServlet
        </servlet-class>
        <init-param>
          <param-name>buffered</param-name>
          <param-value>1</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
          <param-name>debug</param-name>
          <param-value>0</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
          <param-name>expires</param-name>
          <param-value>666</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
          <param-name>isVirtualWebappRelative</param-name>
          <param-value>false</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>4</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
-->

<!--
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>cgi</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.apache.catalina.servlets.CGIServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
          <param-name>cgiPathPrefix</param-name>
          <param-value>WEB-INF/cgi</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>5</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
-->

    <!-- The mapping for the default servlet -->
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>default</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <!-- The mappings for the JSP servlet -->
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>jsp</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.jsp</url-pattern>
        <url-pattern>*.jspx</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <!-- The mapping for the SSI servlet -->
<!--
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>ssi</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.shtml</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
-->

    <!-- The mapping for the CGI Gateway servlet -->

<!--
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>cgi</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/cgi-bin/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
-->

</web-app>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you may have been looking at some other examples on stackoverflow or on the web.  Your namespace declarations are not matching what is the the web.xml you are trying to transform.  "http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" does not match "http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"

Try the following modified XSLT:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
        xmlns:jee="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
        xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
        exclude-result-prefixes="jee">
        
  <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="ISO-8859-1"/>

        <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
                <xsl:copy>
                        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
                </xsl:copy>
        </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="jee:servlet">
        <xsl:copy>
            <!-- copy its children -->
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
            <!-- Add a new elements -->
              <init-param>
                  <param-name>readonly</param-name>
                  <param-value>true</param-value>
              </init-param>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Ah, I see. Yes, I was going off of several different examples, one of which was from another user also trying to manipulate a web.xml. This works, so thank you very much.